# Asp.Net Sample Program For Linux

Tags: asp.net, linux

I have set up .Netcore on my Linux VPS running Ubuntu 14.04. It would be great if I could get a sample web app to test it out. I have tried the one on Microsoft's website but it only works locally (localhost:5000) and I couldn't figure out how to change that. If you guys can tell me how to do it that would be really great.(https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started.html)

Comment: What do you mean by non-locally? You'd like to access it from another machine on your internal network? Or, you'd like it to be accessible from the internet? (And with a domain name?)

Comment: What I meant is that I want to change the port from 5000 to 80

Comment: OK, that's still running locally... Your question was really misleading; why didn't you title it something like "How to set the port for an Asp.Net server"? I have no personal experience in the .net framework, but a 5 second google found me [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx); does that answer your question?